# How to set the php path when directly run php in command prompt

Tags: php, mysql, linux, bash, centos

Hi I have configured php from source package and its install in `/usr/local/bin/php` the version was 5.2  but I have upgraded the PHP using yum repository to 5.4 which is installed in `/usr/bin/php`

whenever I  type

```
root@server1:- which php 
/usr/local/bin/php
```

showing this path and version is

```
root@server1:- php -v 
PHP 5.2.6 (cli) (built: Oct  9 2013 07:08:43)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

and when type

```
root@server1;- /usr/bin/php -v 
PHP 5.4.22 (cli) (built: Nov 18 2013 13:25:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

how do i set a default path of php to 5.4 version no need to use full path while using php

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a bash alias in your `.bash_profile`:

```
alias php="/usr/bin/php"
```